# why solr jdbc only support solrCloud? the single node can get this feature?

Tags: jdbc, solr, solrcloud

I want to use the solr jdbc in my project base on single node. But it noly support solrCloud? so the single node can get this feature?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the SQL feature of Solr is a Mapreduce task built on top of parallell processing on the nodes. This [requires a collection to keep track of SQL plans and available workers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parallel+SQL+Interface#ParallelSQLInterface-ParallelSQLQueries). Since this feature uses the collection API (and doesn't have an alternative implementation), and the JDBC driver connects to *ZooKeeper* (and not to Solr directly) to get information about your Solr cluster, Cloud mode is required for JDBC and SQL support.

You *could* run in SolrCloud-mode with a single node, and you can also run multiple instances on a single server (like having a cluster with three nodes, but only a single server).

I don't think having this support work with a non-cloud setup would be a very high priority task, as the SQL feature is rather new and experimental and cloud mode is becoming more of a norm (and "cloud mode" and "old mode" will probably be merged to a single mode later).